# Segue from tableView to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, controller, segue

Hi I have a tableViewController with cells and I want it to segue to a picture when you click the cell. Considering the MVC design Pattern would it be recommended to create a new viewcontroller for the imageView or would the tableViewController be able to handle the information? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds exactly what is described in the first example of this [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html) and you can use a solution detailed in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518249/is-there-a-simple-uiviewcontroller-that-displays-one-photo).

Comment: surprisingly these two links answered exactly what I was wondering, thanks